# How to send single String to Apple Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I write an app to track my coordinates and my altitude while hiking and wanted to display my altitude on the ApplWatch, but i have no clue how to send a single string to may Watch. In Books and the Internet i only find about sending dictionaries.

If someone could help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WCSession` to send messages (as dictionaries) from the main target to the watch target after the phone and the watch `paired`.

Send a message from main target:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
     WCSession.default.sendMessage(["messageContent": "YOUR MESSAGE HERE"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
}
```

Receive the message from watch target:

```
extension InterfaceController: WCSessionDelegate {
    // ...

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        if let messageContent = message["messageContent"] as? String {
            self.yourLabel.setText(messageContent) // "YOUR MESSAGE HERE"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you read my comment? the first code is in your MAIN TARGET, the second code is in WATCH TARGET.